# Mocha SonarQube does not recognize Node.JS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube, mocha.js, sonarqube-scan

I am using Mocha with SonarQube to test my Node.JS application. It runs on Jenkins.
This is my dependency in package.json:

```
"mocha-sonarqube-reporter": "^1.0.1",
"sonarqube-scanner": "^2.6.0"
```

This is my script:

```
const scanner = require("sonarqube-scanner");
scanner(
  {
    serverUrl: "http://sonarqube.dp-common-quality.svc.cluster.local:9000",
    token: "60c98634b2c56a9948d0bfbb4e2d1286779368a4",
    options: {
      "sonar.projectVersion": "1.0.0",
      "sonar.sourceEncoding": "UTF-8",
      "sonar.log.level": "TRACE",
      "sonar.verbose": "true",
      "sonar.scm.disabled": "true",
      "sonar.sources": "BusinessLogic, routes, bin, app.js",
      "sonar.tests": "tests",
      "sonar.test.inclusions": "tests/apitests.js",
      "sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath": "test_reports",
      "sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath": "coverage/lcov.info",
      "sonar.testExecutionReportPaths": "test_reports/sonarqube/test_results.xml"
    }
  },
  () => process.exit()
);
```

`test_reports/sonarqube/test_results.xml` is generated but when sonarqube scanner runs, it reports the following error:
`06:58:49.445 ERROR: Caused by: Line 2 of report refers to a file with an unknown language: tests/apitests.js`
Any advice and insight is appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I didn't set up a new project for my Node.JS in SonarQube server.